# Inheritance of property characteristic by sub-properties

Tags: rdf, owl, description-logic

In OWL, is a sub-property of an irreflexive property also irreflexive? Likewise is a sub-property of an asymmetric property also asymmetric?

Logically, they should be, but I can't find anything in the OWL documentation that specifies that this is the case.

Consider the following example:

```
:parent-of a owl:IrreflexiveProperty .

:father-of a owl:ObjectProperty ;
    owl:subPropertyOf :parent-of .
```

Based on this ontology, the following would not be allowed because `parent-of` is irreflexive:

```
_:max :parent-of _:max .
```

But is `father-of` implicitly irreflexive as well? In other words, would this also be prohibited:

```
_max :father-of _:max .
```

If you think of a property as a set of arrows which connect pairs of points, then *irreflexive* just means that there are no arrows which both start and end at the same point. A sub-property is simply a subset of those arrows, and so the sub-property of an irreflexive property is necessarily also irreflexive. Likewise with asymmetric properties. But again, I don't know if OWL spells this out explicitly or if OWL reasoners are supposed to make this "assumption".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *In OWL, is a sub-property of an irreflexive property also irreflexive?
>   Likewise is a sub-property of an asymmetric property also asymmetric?*

Yes. The logical formulation is in [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language Direct Semantics (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-direct-semantics-20121211/):

> #### [2.3.2 Object Property Expression Axioms](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-direct-semantics-20121211/#Object_Property_Expression_Axioms)
>
> Satisfaction of OWL 2 object property expression axioms in I is
>   defined as shown in Table 6.
>
> …
>
> - Axiom: IrreflexiveObjectProperty( OPE )
> - Condition: ∀ *x* : *x* ∈ *Δ<sub>I</sub>* implies ( *x , x* ) ∉ *(OPE)<sup>OP</sup>*

Your reasoning shows that any subproperty of an irreflexive property satisfies the condtition.  Therefore, the subproperty is also irreflexive.

> *But again, I don't know if OWL spells this out explicitly or if OWL
>   reasoners are supposed to make this "assumption".*

OWL reasoners are based on these definitions, and so should be able to *infer* that the subproperty is irreflexive.